# Best practice exception handling

Tags: c#, exception

Comming from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0yd65esw.aspx), I'm  not sure about exception handling. MSDN shows the frist way. Is the second one also ok? It's shorter and should produce the same output.

Question: Can I use the second way without any side effects?

```
try
{
    string s = null;
    ProcessString(s);
}
catch (ArgumentNullException e)
{
    LogError(e.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogError("Error");
}
```

or

```
try
{
    string s = null;
    ProcessString(s);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogError((e is ArgumentNullException) ? e.Message : "Error");
}
```

Comment: Both are more or less equivalent in result. But your are asking for best practise. So both are equaliy bad as they are hiding information behind the expression "Error".

Comment: What if I have `SomeWeirdException` thrown? Just an `"Error"`record in the log to use my *crystal ball* in order to understand what's went wrong…

Comment: @Toshi : In the way that they achieve the same with different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, logging "Error" string when you have unknown exception is very bad practice. You should log error details - message, inner exception(s) etc. That's why logging frameworks provide methods which accept `Exception` object which would be logged.

Next, you *should catch separate types of exception only if you handle them differently*. In your case there is simple error logging in both cases, so you don't need to distinguish `ArgumentNullException` from other exceptions:

```
try
{
    ProcessString(null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogError("Failed to process string", e);
}
```

And last - don't write your own logging framework - take a look on [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), log4net etc.

---

Also note that usually you should handle only high-level exceptions. E.g. if you have `ArgumentNullException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you are trying to do some business operation, it's not good to show these low-level exceptions to user. You usually wrap them in custom high-level exception (e.g. `DataMigrationException`) and handle them later

Comment: @Toshi What do you mean by behaving equal?

Comment: with the same input they produce the same output

Comment: LogError could also be a display method for the user and i only want to show `ArgumentNullException` to him

Comment: @Toshi yes, result will be same

Comment: @Toshi well, you are asking about best practice of exception handling

Answer (score 0):

The answer really is "*it depends*".

It's not that bad, but more specific exceptions are better.  When you're more specific, it means that you actually understand, more concretely, what your application is trying to do as well as have more control over it.  You should really just handle the exceptions you expect, and treat everything else as a bug.

If you're specifically catching the exceptions that you know a code block or method can throw, then there's a higher likelihood you can actually recover instead of just logging and hoping for the best.